# irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For any positive integer n and any prime p, we observe that $x^n − p$
is irreducible over Q (per Eisenstein's criterion). Why is this true?

Example: $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1)$, where $1=1/1 \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $a_i=2, p=1$

Comment: If you are asking why Eisenstein's criterion is true, try here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Basic_proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 is not considered as a prime.

Comment: Correct but I think this should have been a comment. He/she might have been able to improve the question.

Comment: Ahhhhh, of course. Thanks